# Need Renters Advice For Mouse Infestation

Tags: rental-property

If a renter is in a unit where there are rodents in a common area such as the dumpster and the landlord fails to take action on the issue (after being notified). Can the renter mitigate the issue themselves? Will they be held liable for any damage that their mitigation may cause?

Comment: Much of that depends on your lease; does the lease say anything about residents using traps or poison? And local laws; there may be restrictions on what you can do in public and on private property; what city/state are you in?

Comment: The lease does not mention anything to that effect. The property is located in california.

Comment: Are you certain that a dumpster and its immediate surroundings is considered a rental unit’s “common area”? I typically think of that as a living room in a house or the lobby in an apartment building.

Comment: I'm not sure. What I know is that we have a rat problem in the dumpster which needs to be fixed and which the landlord has not done anything. My goal is to explore what solutions are possible here.